# Clean Yeoman install results in a Grunt error

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am running `grunt server` after a clean install of Yeoman, using the Webapp generator and I get the following error:

`Warning: Errno::ENOENT on line 441 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/nfento/Sites/test/app/bower_components
    Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.`

Any idea what would be causing this? I have been able to reproduce the error on two machines. I'm completely new to using grunt, but have used it as a server with livereload previously.

Comment: What's in your app/bower_components directory? If one doesn't exist, running `bower install` will look at the dependencies specified in `bower.json`, download them, and put them in that folder.

Comment: What happens when you install ruby1.9.1 ? `ENOENT` sounds familiar to me - it ceased when I installed ruby1.9, but I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a bit late but:

- check if you have a `app/bower_components` folder
- if not check if there is a `bower_components` folder in the root
- if it exists move it in the `/app` folder
- create a file `.bowerrc`and paste this in:

`{"directory": "app/bower_components"}`